# Remove 'X-Requested-With' from query string url during ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The problem I am having is that `&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1462736803425` keeps being appended to my url because it is apart of the query string. Is there a way that I can stop it from becoming a query string and doing `Ajax.BeginForm` without doing a 'hack'?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Filter", new { Area = "Music" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "body-wrapper", OnSuccess = "updateHistory" }, new { @id = "search-form" }))
{
       <div>
           <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           <input type="search" placeholder="Search" id="search" name="searchString" />
       </div>
}

public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
    //do stuff
    return PartialView();
}
```

On the partial view page I then get the path and query:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
```

The value of `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` is : `http://localhost:1526/Music/Search?searchString=maid&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1462736803425`

And then update the url using History.js:

```
function pushState(target) {
    manualStateChange = false;
    History.pushState(null, null, $("#Request_Url_PathAndQuery").val());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I gone with is this, although it's a hack and not really desirable, so if anyone finds a better way please say. It removes the query string parameter from the url, it works because xhr is always appended at the end.

```
function pushState(target) {
    //Remove the queryString parameter of xhr that gets appened in 117 of ajax-unobtrusive.js
    var index = target.indexOf("?X-Requested-With");
    if (index === -1) 
        index = target.indexOf("&X-Requested-With");

    target = target.replace(target.substring(index), "");

    manualStateChange = false;
    History.pushState(null, $("input#Title").val(), target);
}
```

**Edit. New Answer Based on Mike comment:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new { area = "Media" }, FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "search", data_url = Url.Action("SetSearchTags", "Search", new { Area = "Media" }) }))
{
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" id="search" name="searchString" />

    <div id="filter" name="filter">
        <span><strong>Syntax</strong></span>

        @foreach (var item in SearchContext.SearchFilters)
        {
            <div id="filter-@item">
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}

$("form#search").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var searchString = $form.find("input[type='search']").val();
    var url = $form.attr("action");
    var method = $form.attr("method");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { searchString: searchString },
        method: method,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#body-content').html(data);
            updateHistory(true);
        }
    });
});

function updateHistory(useQuery) {
    var path = (useQuery === true) ? $("#Request_Url_PathAndQuery").val() : $("#Request_Url_AbsolutePath").val();

    pushState(path);
};
```

Basically, wherever I need query string parameters I'll just have to manually do it in jquery and not use helpers.

Answer (score 4):

Without altering the source file for ["jquery-ajax-unobtrusive.js"](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/blob/master/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js), it is not easy. The problem here is on line 117:

```
options.data.push({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" });
```

It's adding that data before sending the request. That's kind of obnoxious, especially as that value should be an HTTP header, not part of the data, in my opinion.

There *might* be a way of removing it by adding a `beforeSend` option to the form's ajax request. Namely, you'd want to define a function:

```
function removeExtraData(jqXHR, settings) {
  if (settings.data.hasOwnProperty('X-Requested-With')) {
    delete settings.data['X-Requested-With']; // or settings.data['X-Requested-With'] = undefined;
  }
}
```

You can then use that by adding a `data-ajax-begin` HTML attribute with the value `removeExtraData` to your form. I haven't verified that, and it's been a few years since I've used WebForms, so I don't have a setup to test.

The `_=1462736803425` part of the URL is automatically appended by jQuery because the request is set to not be cached. Apparently you can get rid of that by adding an HTML attribute to your form with the name `data-ajax-cache` and the value `true`. Of course, that may end up caching your request, which might not be desireable.

Comment: Thanks for answering, that cleared some things up. `settings` doesn't have a property of `data` though and I can't find the header to delete.

Comment: The only other way I could think of doing this is to not use `Ajax.BeginForm`. Use `Html.BeginForm` and use jQuery directly to submit the form with ajax. That's a fair amount of work though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really annoying that this is even an issue using the ajax helpers.

I'll give you the bounty later if no better answers come up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by overwriting the url path.

In Application_BeginRequest(), you can check for any condition you need and use context.RewritePath() and remove the unnecessary params.

Something like this:

```
    protected override void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e);
        var urlpath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery; //Modify this based on condition
        if(<condition>)
            Context.RewritePath(<updatedpath>);
    }
```

This may solve your problem but I can't really say if this is a good approach.

Comment: This is a method in the MVC pipeline. If you don't have custom implmentation, you can use this directly because it calls base function as well.